# How to get Visual Studio Code language support to recognize new functions in SQL syntax highlighting

Tags: visual-studio-code, syntaxhighlighter

I develop SQL scripts on Visual Studio Code for Mac (version 1.74.3). In writing dbt models (which are SQL scripts), Visual Studio Code does not recognize certain functions (INITCAP) in one instance as a built-in function and does not highlight this as such. Not the biggest deal, but this got me wondering if I can add INITCAP or other functions to a file or something to get VSC to treat it as a function name. Please help! I search though many Microsoft documentations, but cannot find it. Oh, my files have a .SQL extension so for the most part, the file is recognized as a SQL script.

Comment: Did you notice this page when doing some research on this subject?: [Syntax Highlight Guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/syntax-highlight-guide#:~:text=Syntax%20highlighting%20determines%20the%20color%20and%20style%20of,differently%20than%20strings%20and%20comments%20and%20variable%20names.) for Visual Studio Code

Comment: @Luuk, I did read that very page. I get the feeling that I have to find a plist file where the tokens are stored to make the change, but I couldn't quite figure it out.

Comment: It's somewhere on my wish list to build some day (when I grow up )